# Como obtener la IP o nombre del equipo con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hola buenas tardes estoy tratando de obtener la IP local del equipo a través de javascript ya logre que funcionara en mozila y chrome pero necesito poder obtenerla en internet explorer ya que la empresa donde esta implementado el sistema la mayoria del personal usa internet explorer.... alguna idea o plugin o forma de como obtener la IP en internet explorer con javascript???

Comment: Supongo has usado WebRTC para ello. No podrás hacer lo mismo en IE porque éste navegador **no** implementa ésta API y sinceramente no creo la implemente en un futuro porque Microsoft le presta más atención a Edge. En [éste link](http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/) puedes ver el status actual de ésta API.

Comment: Otra cosa, ¿necesitas hacerlo mediante JavaScript cliente? Con Node.js puedes hacer ésto, al fin y al cabo es JavaScript.

Comment: A tu pregnta le hace falta información. Con qué fin necesitas hallar la dirección ip desde el navegador?, te refieres a la ip de los usuarios que visitan cierta página o la ip del servidor que sirve la página?, tienes algún servidor que sirva páginas? que lenguaje de programación usas en backend?

Comment: @MauroAguilarBustamante dice "ip local", es decir, la ip del equipo.

Comment: @guzgarcia puede que este confundido, si yo quisiera hallar la IP de mi equipo no entiendo que necesidad habría de hacerlo desde uno de mis navegadores.

Comment: @Edwing, antes de publicar mi respuesta a tu pregunta, ¿podrías confirmar que una solución en Node.js te es de ayuda?

Comment: Podrías poner el código que te sirvió en Mozilla, para que la gente mire y evalué por que no sirvió en IE

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/61fb2e7e-0bf8-4b64-b7fd-1e68aaf5aaa5/access-client-local-ip-address-in-ie?forum=ieitprocurrentver Esto te puede ayudar es de la comunidad de windows de microsoft(mejor dicho el soporte)

Answer (score 10):

El presente código funciona en **Mozilla Firefox** y **Google Chrome**, por si alguien lo requiere. En Internet explorer no funciona porque su API no lo ha implementado todavía, esperemos que lo haga pronto, al menos en Edge.

```js
    //obtiene la direccion IP:
    function getIPs(callback){
        var ip_dups = {};
    
        //compatibilidad exclusiva de firefox y chrome, el usuario @guzgarcia compartio este enlace muy util: http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/
        var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
            || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
            || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
        var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    
        //bypass naive webrtc blocking using an iframe
        if(!RTCPeerConnection){
            //NOTE: necesitas tener un iframe in la pagina, exactamente arriba de la etiqueta script
            //
            //<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
            //<script>... se llama a la funcion getIPs aqui...
            //
            var win = iframe.contentWindow;
            RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
                || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
                || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
            useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
        }
    
        //requisitos minimos para conexion de datos
        var mediaConstraints = {
            optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
        };
    
        var servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};
    
        //construccion de una nueva RTCPeerConnection
        var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);
    
        function handleCandidate(candidate){
            // coincidimos con la direccion IP
            var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
            var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];
    
            //eliminamos duplicados
            if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
                callback(ip_addr);
    
            ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
        }
    
        //escuchamos eventos candidatos
        pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){
    
            //dejamos de lado a los eventos que no son candidatos
            if(ice.candidate)
                handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
        };
    
        //creamos el canal de datos
        pc.createDataChannel("");
    
        //creamos un offer sdp
        pc.createOffer(function(result){
    
            //disparamos la peticion (request) al stun server (para entender mejor debemos ver la documentacion de WebRTC.
            pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});
    
        }, function(){});
    
        //esperamos un rato para dejar que todo se complete:
        setTimeout(function(){
            //leemos la informacion del candidato desde la descripcion local
            var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');
    
            lines.forEach(function(line){
                if(line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
                    handleCandidate(line);
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
    
    //Llego la hora de la verdad! vamos a probar: con esto veremos nuestra IP Local:
    getIPs(function(ip){console.log(ip); console.log("saludos hermandad :D !");});
```