# Obtener IP privada del cliente

Tags: javascript, java

¿Existe alguna manera de obtener la dirección IP privada del cliente desde el servidor o pasársela de algún modo sin que se oculte?

Actualmente lo realizo de la siguiente manera:

```js
var ipPrivada = "";
function obtenerIPJS(variable) {

  // NOTE: window.RTCPeerConnection is "not a constructor" in FF22/23
  var RTCPeerConnection = /*window.RTCPeerConnection ||*/ window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;

  if (RTCPeerConnection) (function () {
      var rtc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[]});
      if (1 || window.mozRTCPeerConnection) {      // FF [and now Chrome!] needs a channel/stream to proceed
          rtc.createDataChannel('', {reliable:false});
      };
      
      rtc.onicecandidate = function (evt) {
          // convert the candidate to SDP so we can run it through our general parser
          // see https://twitter.com/lancestout/status/525796175425720320 for details
          if (evt.candidate) grepSDP("a="+evt.candidate.candidate, variable);
      };
      rtc.createOffer(function (offerDesc) {
          grepSDP(offerDesc.sdp, variable);
          rtc.setLocalDescription(offerDesc);
      }, function (e) { console.warn("offer failed", e); });
      
      function updateDisplay(newAddr, variable) {
       var varConEval = eval(variable);
       if (varConEval != "") varConEval = varConEval+",";
       varConEval = varConEval+newAddr;
       eval(variable+" = varConEval");
      }
      
      function grepSDP(sdp, variable) {
          var hosts = [];
          sdp.split('\r\n').forEach(function (line) { // c.f. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566#page-39
              if (~line.indexOf("a=candidate")) {     // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566#section-5.13
                  var parts = line.split(' '),        // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5245#section-15.1
                      addr = parts[4],
                      type = parts[7];
                  if (type === 'host') updateDisplay(addr, variable);
              } else if (~line.indexOf("c=")) {       // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566#section-5.7
                  var parts = line.split(' '),
                      addr = parts[2];
                  updateDisplay(addr, variable);
              }
          });
            console.log("varIP"+eval(variable));
      }
  })(); else {
  }
 }

obtenerIPJS("ipPrivada");
```

El problema es que esto funcionaba antes con otra versión de firefox/chrome (No se con cual). Ahora estos navegadores por defecto ocultan la IP local privada. 
Y la saca con un formato de este estilo : `ej1k-18fa-loquesea.local`
Esta opción de ocultar la IP es algo que se puede cambiar con la variable `#enable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns` del navegador, pero no es una opción.

Lo ideal es que el usuario no tenga que modificar nada en el navegador.

La IP se envía al servidor para comprobar si esta en la lista de IPs validas para realizar esa acción, por lo que la pregunta sería la del inicio:

> ¿Existe alguna manera de obtener la dirección IP privada del cliente
>   desde el servidor o pasársela de algún modo sin que se oculte?

---

Relacionado pero outdated: [Como obtener la IP o nombre del equipo con JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44065/como-obtener-la-ip-o-nombre-del-equipo-con-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No, no se puede.

Históricamente no se ha podido nunca, sencillamente es un dato privado que no necesitabas saber.

Cuando se añadió el protocolo WebRTC [se permitió obtener esa información en las primeras versiones del estándar](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-security-arch-01#section-5.4)... hasta que decidieron que era un problema de seguridad que debía evitarse y en [las versiones actuales se pide que se oculte](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-security-arch-18#section-6.4) de nuevo.