# Obtener mi IP Interna con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

Como se comenta en el título, necesito obtener mi *IP interna (10.xx.xx.xx)* nativamente con `JavaScript` o algun package para Front (`React`).

He probado implementando **[internal-ip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/internal-ip)**, pero por alguna extraña razón debo activar el micrófono - sí, el micrófono - de mi navegador para que me entregue la IP correctamente, sino devuelve `undefined`.

Claramente esta solución no me sirve, porque se debe implementar en dispositivos móviles, pc de escritorio, etc.

De todas formas dejo el extracto de código para que me orienten, si me falta o sobra algo

```
const publicIP = require('react-public-ip')
const internalIP = require('internal-ip')

export const getIpAddress = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch(initGetIpAdresses())
  let IPs = { local: undefined, public: undefined }
  const localIp = await internalIP.v4()
  const publicIp = await publicIP.v4({ fallbackUrl: [ 'https://ifconfig.co/ip' ] })

  IPs = { local: localIp, public: publicIp }

  dispatch(successGetIpAdresses(IPs))
}
```

También probé **[esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44065/como-obtener-la-ip-o-nombre-del-equipo-con-javascript/46438#46438)** solución, que es la que más se repite en los foros, pero me lanza un error cuando trata de obtener el valor de un arreglo. Investigando, llegue a **[esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/342216/obtener-ip-privada-del-cliente)** donde se indica que por privacidad se descartó.

> PD: Se me ocurre que podría buscar algún tipo de package donde pueda
> ejecutar comandos (ipconfig), y guardar el resultado en una variable,
> si alguien sabe de algo parecido también se agradece.

Como siempre, cualquier ayuda u orientación se agradece.

Comment: Dudo que se pueda obtener la IP local sin el uso de librerías porque, tal como mencionas, esta información no está disponible por razones de seguridad. En cuanto a la petición de activar el micrófono, pasa porque la librería usa [RTCPeerConnection](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection) para obtener la IP desde esta API.

Comment: La [otra solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44065/como-obtener-la-ip-o-nombre-del-equipo-con-javascript/46438#46438) que mencionas es una versión anterior lo que hace _internal-ip_ en [browsers.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/internal-ip/blob/main/browser.js), supongo que en algún momento se actualizó la API y dejó de funcionar ese método.

Comment: Entiendo. De todas formas nativamente ya había perdido la esperanza, así que si sabes de alguna librería que me pueda servir, agradecido! El tema del micrófono me complica, ya que al momento de que el aplicativo utilice esa implementación de obtener la IP en un smarthphone, supongo que pedirá permiso al usuario para dicho privilegio, y es algo que quiero evitar.

Comment: Por cuestiones de seguridad y privacidad esos datos no están disponibles. Lo que hace _internal-ip_ es establecer una conexión RTC, pero, nuevamente la seguridad, se requiere que el usuario la permita. Tal vez podrías hacerlo solo una vez, guardando el resultado en _localStorage_ que solo funcionará si el usuario lo acepta, no está en modo privado y no elimina datos del navegador.

Comment: Un panorama oscuro, no veo mucha luz. Habrá que ponerse creativo y abordar el problema desde otra arista. Gracias por la info @Triby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como han dicho, que se pueda conocer la ip local desde un navegador en realidad es un bug y no debería poder hacerse, es por ello que las soluciones que se encuentran tienen que ver con WebRTC, utilizando de alguna manera `RTCPeerConnection`, porque la idea del estandard es conectar dispositivos remotos entre sí, entonces de alguna manera se tienen que comunicar la ip entre ellos. Dicho esto, puede llegar a existir una forma hoy, pero seguramente deje de funcionar pronto.

Por ejemplo algo asi:

```js
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection({
  iceServers: []
});
pc.createDataChannel("");
pc.createOffer(pc.setLocalDescription.bind(pc), () => {});

pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) {
  if (!ice.candidate) return;
  const ipPC = ice.candidate.candidate.split(" ")[4];
  console.log(ipPC)
}
```

Retorna algo como `60X26c2c-14f4-4e3b-a216-3ada952e0b6b.local` que es una ip ofuscada, para deshabilitar eso, en chrome por ejemplo si vamos a chrome://flags/ y ponemos `Anonymize local IPs exposed by WebRTC.` en disabled vamos a ver la ip sin ofuscar.

Dependiendo lo que quieras hacer con la ip local, hay otras opciones. Si fuese posible, es mas fácil el camino inverso, que lo local se conecte con lo remoto, incluso podría enviarle la ip local si fuese necesario. Una posibilidad muy extrema por ejempo, si conoces que tiene que responder lo que buscas, es hacer fuerza bruta a las distintas ips locales con `fetch` hasta encontrar lo que buscas, serían unos 16 millones de fetchs.

Comment: Para explicar mi problematica: en la empresa donde trabajo quieren poder identificar si un trabajador esta usando un equipo corporativo o propio dependiendo de la IP interna de equipo. En una acción POST que existe en el aplicativo, debo enviar esa ip para realizar dicha trazabilidad. Probaré tu respuesta, gracias por darte el tiempo @Emeeus

Comment: Finalmente, tuve que inclinarme por otra opción para lograr lo que necesitaba (sin obtener la IP). De todas maneras, esta respuesta abarca el problema fundamental, que era obtener la ip interna, por lo que la marcaré como correcta. Gracias por tu tiempo @Emeeus